# Do blockchains contain a websocket server?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

I was recently reading about blockchains and am very intrigued by this technology. I had a few questions regarding blockchains:

1. Do Blockchains use web-sockets to transmit information between users? If yes then is the information(blocks) sent always a JSON object?
2. Do all users have the entire copy of the blockchain, do they each just see a partial copy of the blockchain? if yes then how big can the file get?
3. Also, what determines transactions/second? I read bitcoin does about 7transactions/seconds and what is needed to make them more scalable, is it coding factors such as writing a more efficient algorithm (big-O) or is it some kind of hardware limitation?

Sorry if these questions seem trivial but I am a newbie trying to learn the technology. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, usually they use low-level protocol build on top of TCP.
2. Users should have an entire copy of blockchain in order to verify transactions. Database size of Bitcoin: 200 GB, Ethereum 660 GB. You can use lightweight clients, which don't have a full copy, but in this case, you are not part of the network.
3. In Bitcoin, there is a limit on block size, 1 MB. Average transaction size is about 400 bytes, so the average block contains 2000 transactions. There is no problem with increasing block size limit, this was done in Bitcoin Cash network (32 MB). But we cannot increase it to infinity since internet connection speed and transaction verification disk/CPU resources are not infinite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer- about point 3. what determines the limit on block size? I mean how was the 1mb block size for bitcoin determined?

Comment: @pi2018 it was initial limit set by first developers, there is no specific logic here, just initial estimation

Comment: 2. that's not correct enough: lightweight clients (for example SPV clients) are part of the network, they just lack the "full blockchain" functionality. Actually every node which is not a "full node", doesn't store locally the entire blockchain, but is still part of the network.

Comment: @theDima I agree, technically speaking they are part of a network, they connect to other nodes and request data. But I mean, from cryptocurrency network perspective, they are useless for the network. They cannot provide any data to other nodes, they don't increase network security

Comment: "There is no problem with increasing block size limit" - Besides of the resource consumption, wouldn't increasing block size require more time until a transaction can be fully confirmed, since it needs more transactions until it can be added to the blockchain? Or are there always available transactions such that the time difference is negligible?

Comment: @Ixx We can create blocks with no transactions (just with coinbase transaction), and they are valid for the network. We don't need to fulfill entire block size limit.

Comment: @Zergatul okay, but the question is aimed to when you do use the full block size, which I assume is the purpose of the forks that increased it.

Comment: @Ixx whenever miner decides to use it. Miners have full freedom. They may decide to not include any transactions in block. They can include only transactions which satisfy some criteria, for example fee per byte is greater then some value. They can include all transactions even without fee. Maximum block size is just limiting how many transaction bytes they can include. If non-confirmed transaction pool is greater than limit, then the most profitable way for miner is to include only transactions with big fee. That leads to conclusion: bigger block size = smaller fees and quicker confirm. time.