# Does blockchain use websocket?

Tags: websocket, blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, smartcontracts

Im programming an application for sharding on a p2p network but p2p networks have some serious problems like forwarding port , static ips and these things get a lot of time for me and it can be so bad for marketing and users.
After all i wanna use smart contract on a blockchain to pay for it.
Does blockchain use websocket for transfer blocks and data and give miners blocks ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317370/do-blockchains-contain-a-websocket-server

Answer (score 1):

No blockchain's nodes relay transactions and blocks to their neighbours node after that they participate in the validation process.
Ordinary users use wallets which connect to a node, this communication can base on socket or rest api